# Changing properties of all <hr> html elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

In css I have set all the `<hr>` elements in my html to "display:none;"  which works.

I have an onclick event listener set up to change the "display" to "block".

I use:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("hr").innerHTML.style.display = "block";
```

I get an error "Cannot read property 'style' of undefined".

Comment: getElementsByTagName returns an array of nodes.

Comment: ```document.getElementsByTagName("hr")[0].style.display = "block";``` if there is only one hr. Otherwise you need to loop over the ```NodeList``` (which is not a true array so forEach would fail) returned by ```getElementsByTagName```.

Comment: @gillesc Actually you can use `forEach` to iterate a node list, but you have to combine it with `call()`. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30131447/361762) for an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it the following way:

```
var hrItems = document.getElementsByTagName("hr");

for(var i = 0; i < hrItems.length; i++) {
    hrItems[i].style.display = 'block';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is incorrect in two ways

1. `getElementsByTagName` gives you a list on elements and there is no method to operate on all elements, so you'll have to loop through all of them and add the required style individually.
2. `innerHTML` returns a string containing the mark up in an element but `<hr>` doesn't have any thing in it and the `style` property is on the `<hr>` itself.

   ```
   var hrs = document.getElementsByTagName("hr");
   for(var i = 0; i < hrs.length; i++) {
       hrs[i].style.display = 'block';
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Simple (and very effective) solution:

tag your body with a class-element

```
<body class="no_hr">  <article><hr/> TEXT Foo</article> <hr/> </body>
```

in css don't hide hr directly, but do

```
.no_hr hr {
    display:none;
}
```

now define a second style in your css

```
.block_hr hr{
    display:block;
}
```

in your buttons onClick, change the one and only body class from *no_hr* to *block_hr*

```
onclick() {
    if ( document.body.className == "no_hr" ) {
      document.body.className = "block_hr";
    } else {
      document.body.className = "no_hr";
    }        
}
```

This is a very charming solution, because you don't have to iterate over elements yourself, but let your browsers optimized procedures do their job.

Answer (score 1):

For people who want a solution that doesn't require JavaScript.

Create an invisible checkbox at the top of the document and make sure that people can click on it.

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="ruler"/>
<label for="ruler">Click to show or hide the rules</label>
```

Then tell the stylesheet that the `<hr>`s should be hidden by default, but should be visible if the checkbox is checked.

```css
#ruler, hr {display:none}
#ruler:checked ~ hr {display:block}
```

Done. See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/yj8ovL90/).

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByTagName()` returns a node list, and therefore you must iterate through all the results. Additionally, there is no `innerHTML` property of an `<hr>` tag, and the style must be set directly on the tag.

I like writing these types of iterations using [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call):

```
[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName("hr"), function(item) {
  item.style.display = "block";
});
```

Or, make it even easier on yourself and use jQuery:

```
$("hr").show();
```